# Perl string manipulation and utf8/unicode

Tags: mysql, perl, utf-8

I have what i thought was going to be a simple web form until folks started copying and pasting text strings from Wikipedia that contain utf8 characters into an input field.  My perl CGI script opens a MySQL DB connection and sets

```
$DBH->{mysql_enable_utf8} = 1;
$DBH->do("set names 'utf8';");
```

I am trying to use the `Encode` module to decode, use and encode the target input value but that's not working as I expect.  The web page is set with a utf8 character set.

My target string in this case is `Baden-Württemberg` [copied from a Wikipedia page that lists German town names].  When the request is sent I can see the target string as: `Baden-W%C3%BCrttemberg`.  That is not flowing through my CGI script well though.

I have the following sample script:

```
#!/usr/local/bin/perl -w

use strict;
select(STDOUT);
$|++;

use feature 'unicode_strings';
use Encode;
use utf8;

binmode STDOUT, ":utf8";

my $thing = "Baden-Württemberg";
print STDOUT "$thing\n";

my $decodedThing = decode_utf8($thing);
print STDOUT encode_utf8($decodedThing) . "\n";
```

That value of `$thing` has a 'u' with an umlaut over it just after the '-W'.

When I run the script I get:

```
# ./test.pl
Malformed UTF-8 character (unexpected non-continuation byte 0x72, immediately after start byte 0xfc) at ./test.pl line 13.
Baden-Wrttemberg
Baden-Wrttemberg
```

where did the u-umlaut go?  How do I get it back?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`%C3%BC` is the `urlencode` for `ü`.  You do not want that for MySQL, though you might want it when building a URL.

`Ã¼` happens when you store utf8 bytes as if they were latin1 into a latin1 column.  Please provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE`.

I don't think you need encode/decode_utf8 for anything.

> Malformed UTF-8 character (unexpected non-continuation byte 0x72, immediately after start byte 0xfc) at ./test.pl line 13.

indicates that you have hex `FC` (which is the *latin1* hex for `ü`), but you are treating the string as utf8 ("unexpected ..")  `72` is the `r` that follows.

Bottom line:  You are not utf8 throughout the processing (bytes in hand, SET NAMES, CHARACTER SET, etc).

Comment: CREATE TABLE `nameTokens` (
      `id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
      `token` varchar(128) NOT NULL,
      PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
      UNIQUE KEY `token` (`token`)
    ) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=124 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8

Answer (score 3):

### Problem 1

You told Perl your source file was encoded using UTF-8.

```
use utf8;
```

It wasn't. `ü` is represented by `FC` instead of `C3 BC` in your file. (That's why you are getting that "malformed" message.) Fix the encoding of your source file.

```
mv file.pl file.pl~ && piconv -f iso-8859-1 -t UTF-8 file.pl~ >file.pl
```

### Problem 2

The following makes no sense:

```
my $decodedThing = decode_utf8($thing);
```

Because of `use utf8;`, `$thing` will already be decoded.

### Problem 3

The following makes no sense:

```
print STDOUT encode_utf8($decodedThing);
```

You asked Perl to automatically encode every sent to STDOUT, so you're double encoding.

### Fixed

```
#!/usr/local/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;
use utf8;
use open ':std', ':encoding(UTF-8)';

my $thing = "Baden-Württemberg";
printf "U+%v04X\n", $thing;     # U+[...].0057.00FC.0072.[...]
print "$thing\n";               # Baden-Württemberg
```

Answer (score 0):

Turns out Rick James' last line `Bottom line: You are not utf8 throughout the processing (bytes in hand, SET NAMES, CHARACTER SET, etc).` was the key.  I do need the Encode module but only really for the DB insert statements, a la:

```
if (!($sth->execute(encode('UTF-8', $_))) && $DBI::err != 1062) {
    die "DB execute failed :" . $DBI::err . ": " . $DBI::errstr;
}
```

Thanks to you all